# Storing secure strings during sysprep using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have two Powershell scripts I'm building for a Windows 7 image.  Prior to the image I run PRE-IMAGE.ps1, and it has a line like this in it:

```
$JoinDomainPassword = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter the password for $joinDomainUser" -AsSecureString
$strPass = $joinDomainPassword | ConvertFrom-SecureString
```

I then save the the $strPass secure string to the registry, and run sysprep.

After a reboot with sysprep, the POST-IMAGE.ps1 then pulls $strPass from the registry, and has a line like this:

```
$strPass = $strPass | ConvertTo-SecureString
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($JoinDomainUser, $strPass)
```

However, these lines in POST-IMAGE.ps1 get the "Key not valid" error you'll see when you run convertto-securestring and convertfrom-securestring as different Windows users.  ([similiar to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109958/saving-credentials-for-reuse-by-powershell-and-error-convertto-securestring-ke)) - but the catch here is I -AM- using the same user to convert to and from secure strings.  I'm guessing this has something to do with sysprep - but I can't wrap my head around it.

I apologize if this has been asked about before, I've found a few questions that touch on parts of this, but don't describe my EXACT problem.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could save the credentials as a Base64 string. Its not encrypted but it keeps children like levels on intelligence out.

**Convert a string to a Base64 string:**
      [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("**hello**"))

**Convert a Base64 string back to string**
    [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String("**aGVsbG8=**"))

Thais worked for my needs but you may have different concerns.